# Почему "баю-бай" итд? / Why "баю-бай" etc?

Tags: этимология, значения

Почему *баю-бай*, *баюшки*, *басиньки* и т. д. в русском языке ассоциируются со сном? Эти слова и другие, образованные от них, встречаются практически во всех колыбельных. Интересно, чем это вызвано и с каких времен?

Why are words *баю-бай*, *баюшки*, *басиньки* etc. in Russian language associated with sleep?  These words and other similar ones are used in pretty much all lullabies.  I wonder why it is so and since when.

Comment: It is interesting if English *lullaby* has connection with Russian "бай".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, let me point out that questions in form "Why is this specific word associated with this specific concept" are not that good. Why is Russian "хрю" associated with what is described in English with "oink"? Why in vulgar Latin did "caballus" override the usage of "equus"? As to me, those are a bit broader than a valuable question can contain.

Now, about "баю-бай". It is closely related to the russian word "байка", both these words are derivatives of the verb "[баять](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0)" - which can be translated as (among other things) "to cast a spell". The very same root can be met in "обаяние" (charm) and "басня" (fable). Moreover, fable is actually related tо "баять" оn a PIE level.

As for "басиньки" - I guess it's a way to mimic childish speech.

Answer (score 1):

I ба́ю
ба́ять, ба́ить "говорить", укр. ба́яти "рассказывать", русск.-цслав. баю, баяти "рассказывать, заговаривать, лечить", болг. ба́я "колдую", сербохорв. ба̏jати "колдовать", словен. bájati "болтать, говорить, заклинать", чеш. bájiti "говорить, болтать", польск. bajać "болтать", в.-луж. bać – то же, н.-луж. bajaś.

Исконнородственно греч. φημί, дор. φαμί "говорю", φήμη, дор. φά̄μΒ̄ "голос, молва", φωνή "голос", лат. fāri "говорить", fābula "речь, рассказ", др.-исл. bón, bǿn, арм. ban "слово, речь" и т. д.; см. Бернекер 1, 39; Хюбшман 428. Сюда не относится лит. bóju, bóti "обращать внимание" – переразложение лит. atbóti, dabóti "обращать внимание, заботиться", которое заимств. из польск. dbać; см. Лескин, Bildung 457; Остен-Сакен, IF 33, 206 и сл. Дальнейшее см. выше, на ба́сня.
(Ср. еще сев.-фризск. bālen "говорить"; см. Хольтхаузен, PBB 48, стр. 460. – Т.)

II ба́ю
ба́юшки, ба́ю, отсюда (у)баю́кать. По мнению Брандта (РФВ 18, 27), это выражение связано с ба́ю "говорю". Ср., однако, бай-бай.

Comment: Не особо понимаю, как копия определения из словаря отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @AleksG, во-первых, он указал, что в р.я. существует слово "баять" ("баю") в значении "говорить" ("говорю"); во-вторых, он указал на мнение Брандта, что "баю-баюшки" таки связано именно с "баять" в значении "говорить". Как связано -- непонятно, у меня есть два предположения: (1) что "баю" в начале колыбельных изначально никак не было связано со сном, а всего лишь означало "говорить" (ну, например, "я тебе баю, баю, а ты, дитятко, засыпай", но со временем трансформировалось в бессмысленное "баю-бай"); (2) что "баять" независимо от этого...

Comment: ... стало значить "усыплять"/"успокаювать" (сначала было "баять" в значении "говорить", потом появилось "убаюкивать" в значении "забалтывать", "успокаивать болтовнёй" и потом "баюкать" в значении просто "усыплять"/"успокаювать").